# Laravel can't uncheck checkbox using old with default value set

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a very simple checkbox in my application form

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="active" {{ ( empty(old('active')) ? '' : ' checked' ) }}>
```

My requirements are:

1. the checkbox should be checked by default when the user arrives on the site for the first time
2. the checkbox should keep its value after the form validation fails

To me, it seems impossible to achieve this simply by using `old` as it will either

- (2) remember the value after validation fails but it will not be checked by default at the beginning
- (1) be checked by default, e.g. `old('active', true)` but then it will not be possible to uncheck it (i.e. unchecked box will be checked after validation fails because the default value is set in `old`).

What is the standard way of dealing with this? Or is there no way around using another field to check if the form was submitted?

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="active" {{ ( empty(old('active')) && !empty(old('submit')) ? '' : ' checked' ) }}>
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Thank you

Comment: I would do the logic in the controller to figure out if it should be checked or not. It's hard to give more detail than that without knowing how you're doing validation, but you can send your own flash data back to the view method with details about whether the checkbox was checked or not. If the flash data is missing, default to checked. Send that variable into the view, and use it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Just wanted to know if there wasn't something already built for handling checkboxes this way

Comment: How did you solve it? I am facing it right now.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe dirty but you can append empty string if the `$request->active` is `null`.
The code is something like this `$request->active ?? '';`.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass the default value into `old` helper.

Try this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="active" {{ old('active', true) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Comment: .. but if I do this, the checkbox will be checked even after I unchecked it (when the validation fails) because it will default to `true`

Comment: No, just try. 

no old value => 'checked'
old value == true => 'checked'
old value == false => ''

Comment: there's no such thing as old value false ... if the checkbox is not checked`old('active', true)` will be `true` because `old('active')` is not set